# Possible to use SQL to sort by date but put null dates at the back of the results set?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a bunch of tasks in a MySQL database, and one of the fields is "deadline date". Not every task has to have to a deadline date.

I'd like to use SQL to sort the tasks by deadline date, but put the ones without a deadline date in the back of the result set. As it is now, the null dates show up first, then the rest are sorted by deadline date earliest to latest.

Any ideas on how to do this with SQL alone? (I can do it with PHP if needed, but an SQL-only solution would be great.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Here's a solution using only standard SQL, not ISNULL().  That function is not standard SQL, and may not work on other brands of RDBMS.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE ...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN myDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, myDate;
```

Comment: +1. Here's another elegant and compact standard solution (available since [SQL:2003 extension T611](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by), although not all vendors implement this functionality): http://stackoverflow.com/a/12767777/814702.

Comment: @informatik01, good tip, but this question is tagged `mysql` and MySQL doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yeah, sad. Only checked this on PostgreSQL 9.1, where it works just fine. Anyways, let this info be here just for the sake of completeness. P.S. Just noticed that when using `ORDER BY` MySQL and PostgreSQL behave differently: when ordering *ascending* MySQL  puts NULL values **first**, while PostgreSQL puts NULL values **last**. Well, vendor specific stuff ...

Comment: To explain how this works - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985068/why-does-this-sql-order-null-values-last#26985092

Comment: Yes, NULLS FIRST is an example of something that makes this simple task simple, but sadly not all DBMSs support it.  Another example of a simple task that some DBMSs make really difficult is dropping a table only if it exists. http://www.ehow.com/how_4738206_database-table-only-already-exists.html

Comment: @BillKarwin - I am new to sql. Why can't we do `order by desc` for the column which has nulls ? That seems to work for me.

Comment: @MasterJoe, you can order by any column you want. But in MySQL, NULL is ordered before any other value. You could use `order by ... desc` as you say, but then all the values would be sorted in reverse order. I assume the question wants them sorted ascending, except for NULLs which should be _after_ all other values.

Answer (score 29):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ISNULL(myDate), myDate
```

Comment: ISNULL requires 2 arguments on SQL Server. Does MySQL only require one?

Comment: yep - only one. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull

Comment: Note that, in the case of Access/VBA, `True < False`, so you may need `ORDER BY Not IsNull (field), field`.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT foo, bar, due_date FROM tablename
ORDER BY CASE ISNULL(due_date, 0)
WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, due_date
```

So you have 2 order by clauses. The first puts all non-nulls in front, then sorts by due date after that

Comment: "case isnull(due_date, 0) when 0 then 1 else 0" - why bother doing all that? isnull returns 1 or 0 anyway.

Comment: In MSSQL, ISNULL returns its first argument, or its second argument if its first argument is null.  There's a standard SQL function COALESCE which does the same and also accepts more than two arguments.  But this is a bit off-topic since the poster is asking about MySQL....

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is using the minus operator with DESC.

`SELECT * FROM request ORDER BY -date DESC`

In MySQL, NULL values are considered lower in order than any non-NULL value, so sorting in ascending (ASC) order NULLs are listed first, and if descending (DESC) they are listed last.

When a - (minus) sign is added before the column name, NULL become -NULL.

Since -NULL == NULL, adding DESC make all the rows sort by date in ascending order followed by NULLs at last.