# nhibernate - sort null at end

Tags: nhibernate

Using NHibernate from C# and only HQL (not SQL) in a way that is compatible with MS SQL Server 2005/2008 (and preferably Oracle).

Is there a way to write the order by clause so that nulls will sort at the end of the query results while the non-null results will be sorted in ascending order?

Based on the answer to the question referenced by nickf the answer is:

```
select x from MyClass x order by case when x.MyProperty is null then 1 else 0 end, x.MyProperty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this helps or not, but there's [another question asking the same thing about how to do this with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151195).

Perhaps the same logic could be applied to HQL?

---

edit: this got accepted, so apparently, yes it can.

Here's the accepted answer from that question (by [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860)):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE ...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN myDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, myDate;
```

Comment: If you're looking for QueryOver, find it at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12428891/9344.

Answer (score 0):

At one point I just gave up and fixed the sort order in my collection class.

Since I was just moving NULLs all I had to do was peel off the nulls at the beginning of the collection and append them to the end.

With a bet of cleaver coding, it can even be done on an array.

Nevertheless, that ORDER BY CASE is a cleaver and readable trick.