# MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Currently I am doing a very basic OrderBy in my statement.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE visible=1 ORDER BY position ASC, id DESC
```

The problem with this is that NULL entries for 'position' are treated as 0. Therefore all entries with position as NULL appear before those with 1,2,3,4. eg:

```
NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Is there a way to achieve the following ordering:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL.
```

Comment: You should reconsider user1052645's answer. It's simpler, requires no knowledge of max values, and could be faster (assuming evaluating an expression may be faster than a function call).

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8174026/470530) is **WRONG**!!!!! See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=427a8a0dd63fe710ce949b03ae72ab69) and [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=30b5babbdecd20d7724c77fe2abc2056) - the `ISNULL (field), field ASC` works as does the `CASE` solution!

Comment: @SteveClay who was user1052645?

Comment: `ORDER BY COALESCE(column_name, 'zz') DESC`

Comment: @Adam, user1052645 is [Jarred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8174026/1019059).

Answer (score 670, accepted):

MySQL has an undocumented syntax to sort nulls last.  Place a minus sign (-) before the column name and switch the ASC to DESC:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE visible=1 ORDER BY -position DESC, id DESC
```

It is essentially the inverse of `position DESC` placing the NULL values last but otherwise the same as `position ASC`.

A good reference is here http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms#select-order_by

Comment: It's not undocumented, `- col_name` is an expression (`0 - col_name`), which the ORDER BY clause accepts. Of course this only works for numeric columns.

Comment: Nice one. Works for `date` and `time` columns too! (MySQL 5.5). I guess (i am lazy to check) it works for all number-like columns (timestamp, float...).

Comment: Be careful as this is undocumented and may be removed in future revisions

Comment: @koral: it is a simple (and useful) math expression that reverses the order, it won't be removed unless the language itself dramatically change.

Comment: As the comments suggest, it works for numeric, date and time columns? But, what about varchar? Can it be applied for varchar as well? I tried applied it to varchar fields, but the order seems to be different than from using either ASC or DESC.

Comment: Won't this prevent the usage of an possible index on the order by column?

Comment: for varchar I  used  order by COALESCE(cn.our_name, cn.name,"яяяяяяяяяя") ';   , if your language is English , replace яяяя with zzzzzz

Comment: It works for dates, numeric, characters, ENUM, booleans,.. remember the minus `-` cast characters to 0, those come before 'null' when `ORDER BY DESC`. Notice though, for characters, that will leave you without any particular order for non null values.

Comment: this will only work for date time and number. alpha numeric and alphabetic will not work.

Comment: Doesn't work on a float column, spits out values in what seems random order.

Comment: To clarify you reverse the sort order, with NULLS at the end then just remove the negative sign and keep the sort order the same

Comment: **Doesn't work!** See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=328268af28fc4a0bb1aebbccc87b292a) - you can see the first two `SELECT`s show that your solution (which I unfortunately upvoted) fails!

Comment: Just to pile on for anyone else on the fence about this answer: use `ORDER BY ISNULL(field)`.  This answer has several significant drawbacks.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 386):

I found this to be a good solution for the most part:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ISNULL(field), field ASC;
```

Comment: Without redefining order by works: ```SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ISNULL(field) ASC;``` (MySQL 5.5)

Comment: Nice! I use this variation for empty fields: `SELECT *, position = '' as has_position FROM table ORDER BY has_position, position`

Comment: The accepted solution does not work with TIMESTAMP in postgresql 9.3.  This solution does...

Comment: This can be used for text fields as well... nice.

Comment: To move empty and null fields to the end, I would use this query: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ISNULL(field), (field = '');`

Comment: Annoyingly, MySQL won't use an index on field when you add isnull(field) to the order by clause (when using limit).

Comment: @kalu: In **PostgreSQL**, NULL values are sorted *last* in ascending order (and first in descending order). And you would rather use the [*standard SQL* clause `NULLS LAST` | `NULLS FIRST`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860) to flip it instead of the workarounds here.

Comment: @kalu Note that the question is tagged specifically as "mysql".

Comment: @BarryKelly You can add new virtual column
`isNullField GENERATED ALWAYS AS ISNULL(field) VIRTUAL`
add it to the index and use for ordering. VIRTUAL fieldss not use disk space for data, only for index.

Comment: @Crusader a fine choice if you're working with 5.7.6 or above

Comment: It sounds like @kalu may be hoping to use the same statements in MySQL and PostgreSQL...which would be unwise in any case

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The -sort_column trick doesn't even work on all types of columns.  This answer does work perfectly fine! Thanks

Comment: This solution works with numbers and strings as well: it should be marked as best answer. The current best answer works only with numbers.

Comment: @MarçalJuan
_it's just the same query but shorter_.
No, it's not. `ISNULL(field), field ASC` pushes `NULL` to the end AND sorts non-nullable values. Your solution only pushes `NULL` to the end.

Comment: @Boolean_Type Thanks! Nostalgic to read my answer from 10 years ago :-)

Answer (score 44):

**NULL LAST**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id IS NULL, id ASC
```

Comment: nice working solution, can you explain it?

Answer (score 25):

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where visible=1 ORDER BY COALESCE(position, 999999999) ASC, id DESC
```

Replace 999999999 with what ever the max value for the field is

Comment: This solution is fragile and may lead to intermittent bugs

Answer (score 6):

This works well for me as well.

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(field), field = 0 ASC;
```

Returns
1
2
3
0
0
null
null

Answer (score 4):

You can swap out instances of NULL with a different value to sort them first (like 0 or -1) or last (a large number or a letter)...

```
SELECT field1, IF(field2 IS NULL, 9999, field2) as ordered_field2
  FROM tablename
 WHERE visible = 1
 ORDER BY ordered_field2 ASC, id DESC
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem as the index referenced in ORDER BY will not be affected by replacing values in the SELECT statement, and thereby won't correct the ordering. Also, check out the COALESCE function, which is functionally equivalent to your use of the IF function.

Comment: If you alias the IF statement properly, the rows are ordered as you'd expect.  I fixed my example.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE visible=1 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN position IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,id DESC
```

Comment: No need for case. IS NULL returns 1 when expression is NULL. See reverbnation's answer.

Answer (score 4):

For a `DATE` column you can use:

---

**NULLS last:**

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(`myDate`, '9999-12-31') ASC
```

**Blanks last:**

```
ORDER BY IF(`myDate` = '', '9999-12-31', `myDate`) ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

That's simple. You just need to order twice:

- first step, order NULLs
- second step, order your field.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name 
ORDER BY ISNULL(field_name), field_name;
```

It works with any types, including JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You can [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) your NULLs in the `ORDER BY` statement:

```
select * from tablename
where <conditions>
order by
    coalesce(position, 0) ASC, 
    id DESC
```

If you want the NULLs to sort on the bottom, try `coalesce(position, 100000)`. (Make the second number bigger than all of the other `position`'s in the db.)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE visible=1 ORDER BY CASE WHEN `position` = 0 THEN 'a' END , position ASC
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**To achieve following result :**

`1, 2, 3, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL.`

USE syntax, place `-(minus sign)` before field name and use inverse order_type(Like: If you want order by ASC order then use DESC or if you want DESC order then use ASC)

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE visible=1 ORDER BY -position DESC`

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY position = 0, position ASC;
```

---

```
position
1 
2
3
0
0
```

Answer (score -9):

Why don't you order by NULLS LAST?

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE visible = 1 
ORDER BY position ASC NULLS LAST, id DESC
```

Comment: `NULLS LAST` - what version of MySQL was that introduced?

Comment: @Panique, You mean (MS) SQL Server?

Comment: this answer doesn't apply to MySQL

Comment: this solution works for java db but not not for mysql