# ROR application - trying to change default scope order

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

I have a database with tables `Exchanges`, `Company`, and `Company_Listings`.

```
Exchanges table
  name
  full_name

Companies table
  name
  full_name
  exchange_id

Company_Listings table
  company_id
  exchange_id
  company_code
  option_name
  [...] other columns
```

If the listing is a company it will have a `company_code` e.g. BHP and if it is a company option it will have a `option_name` e.g. BHPXX but no `company_code`.  Both with link via `company_id` to the company "Broken Hill Billiton Pty Ltd."

```
Exchanges model
  has_many :companies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :company_listings, dependent: :destroy 

Companies Model 
  belongs_to :exchange
  has_many :company_listings,

Company_Listing Model
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :exchange
  default_scope { order('exchange_id ASC', 'company_code ASC', 'option_name ASC') }
```

The default scope orders company listings as BHP, CBA ... BHPXX.

I am trying to get the sort so that it gives BHP, BHPXX, CBA. Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`default_scope { order('company_code ASC', 'option_name ASC', 'exchange_id ASC')`

If that doesn't work because of the nulls, you may need to look at how it's done here:

[ORDER BY ASC with Nulls at the Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993109/order-by-asc-with-nulls-at-the-bottom)

[MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last)

`default_scope { order('-company_code DESC', '-option_name DESC', 'exchange_id ASC')`

EDIT: the above may not work here given that company_code and option_name are not numeric in nature, but the links provide plenty of other ways to do this.