# Sorting laravel collection by leaving null/empty last

Tags: php, laravel, collections, usort

Can't seem to get my head around of sorting laravel collection so `empty` / `null` data would end up being last. ( bit confused about usort )

Pretty much all I have is bunch of `times` / `timestamps` that need to be ordered. Some rows may not have for that column.

I would like data to appear `ASC` / `ascending` while `empty/null` data is shown last.

`$collection->sortBy('timestamp')` sorts nicely but doesn't know how to deal with empty fields.

[image: data]

Table looks like this.

```
   $data = $data->sort(function($a, $b) use ($sortBy) {
        if ($a->{$sortBy} and $b->{$sortBy}) return 0; 
        return ($a->{$sortBy} > $b->{$sortBy}) ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

Random code I tried from the internet, which I can't get to work correctly. 
`$sortBy` contains a field name to sort by ( since it may change )
Faulty code deals with empty / null data but its out of order.
[image: faulty]

Comment: Please add code you are using for sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`$collection->sortBy('-timestamp')`

Does it work?

Comment: This post gave me idea thanks to what I think I got it working. Instead of having sortBy('-timestamp'), I created another variable for each entry  for example: timestamp_order to which I assigned by default value, random number of -10000 and that variable gets overwritten if there is any data ( timestamp is not null or empty ). Then sorted by $collection->sortBy('timestamp_order')

Comment: I don't like that idea, but glad it works :) If my suggestion doesn't work, maybe try using CASE, like following example:

`ORDER BY (CASE WHEN timestamp IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END), timestamp`

Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993109/order-by-asc-with-nulls-at-the-bottom

Comment: Didn't like that idea too much either, but since I have many relations atm and limited time frame to figure it out then I'm sorting collection instead. Changed the random number to Carbon::now()->addYear()->toDateTimeString(); instead and since they are older than any other timestamps then they appear last.

Answer (score 7):

Have to use sort() with a closure. Below will sort timestamp ASC with NULL at the end.

```
$sorted = $collection->sort(function ($a, $b) {
    if (!$a->timestamp) {
        return !$b->timestamp ? 0 : 1;
    }
    if (!$b->timestamp) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a->timestamp == $b->timestamp) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $a->timestamp < $b->timestamp ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. In my case, the `time` attribute of a `$result` might be `NULL`. It acts as if `NULL` is `0` (as `int`) and that's expected behavior. But I also wanted to sort the collection by leaving `NULL` last.

```
$collection->sortBy(function ($result) {
    if ($result['time'] === NULL) {
        return PHP_INT_MAX;
    }

    return $result['time'];
});
```

You can achieve this simply by returning an value higher in the alphabetical order compared to all other values in the array. i.e. `PHP_INT_MAX` to be safe. This will make sure all the results where the `time` equals `NULL` are at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Mr. Speelman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64538351/678951), but as a shorter PHP 7.4+ version:

```
$collection->sortBy(fn($e) => $e->timestamp ?: PHP_INT_MAX)
```

Answer (score -3):

I assume your `timestamp` is unix timestamp.

You can sort it like this :

```
$sorted = $collection->sortByDesc('timestamp');
```

Comment: This wouldn't be what I want to achieve, I'd like results to appear ASC / Ascending while empty / null data is last.