# How to sort a Laravel collection with sortBy(), ascending, and have NULL values placed last instead of first

Tags: laravel, sorting, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-collection

Laravel's `Collection` class (v5.5) has a `sortBy()` method that sorts everything similar to if you had used a SQL `ORDER BY` statement, except there is one striking difference: a relational database will put `NULL` values at the end when sorting ascending (or at least PostgreSQL does), but Laravel's `sortBy()` method puts `NULL` values first.

So how do I get those `NULL` values to be sorted last instead of first when using the `Collection::sortBy()` method? **PLEASE NOTE: I cannot change the database query itself! MY ONLY OPTION is to sort the Collection itself within PHP. I absolutely cannot do this at the database level in my situation.**

There is a [similar question on Stack Overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449707/sorting-laravel-collection-by-leaving-null-empty-last/43454448) but the solution OP found was kind of a hack and does not work in my situation, because I need it to work for varchars.

NOTE: I realize `sortBy()` accepts a Closure for the first argument but there is [zero explanation in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) about the arguments this closure receives (which "key" is `$key`?), nor does it explicitly say what the closure is supposed to return in order to determine the sort order. (I'm assuming it should return an integer representing the order, but I do not know how to make that work for me with multiple `NULL` values.)

Comment: Please show the real data sample so we could use it to find working solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sortBy` method accepts a field on which to sort, in *ascending order*. So if you had a collection of `App\User` objects, you could pass in say `first_name` and that would sort by each user's first name.

If your logic is more complex, and you wanted to sort on something that isn't strictly a *field* of each item in your collection you may pass a closure instead. The first parameter passed to the closure is the actual item. You should return a value that you want to be sorted from the closure. Let's say in your collection of `App\User` objects, you wanted to sort by the last letter of each person's first name:

```
$users->sortBy(function ($item) {
    return substr($item->first_name, -1);
});
```

The second parameter is the key, which is the key of the collection, or the underlying array it represents. If you've retrieved a collection from the database, this will likely be a numeric index, but if you had a different collection or you decided to re-key the collection by say, the user's email address (Using `keyBy`), then that is what is passed.

When it comes to sticking all of your `null` values at the end of the sorted result set, I would suggest using the `sort` method instead of `sortBy`. When you pass a closure to `sort`, it accepts two items, representing two items from your collection to be sorted. In the case of your collection of `App\User` objects, each item would an instance of `App\User`. This gives you total control on how two objects are compared and therefore total control over the order.

You should return `-1` (or a negative value) if the first item is considered to be less than the second, you should return `0` if the two items are to be considered equal and `1` (or a positive value) if the first item is considered to be greater than the second.

```
$users->sort(function ($a, $b) {
    // Return -1, 0 or 1 here
});
```

That should allow you to implement your logic. To ensure `null` values are moved to the end, just return `1` every time whatever you're interested in from `$a` is `null`. Similarly, if whatever you're interested in from `$b` is `null`, return `-1` and if whatever you're interested in from both `$a` and `$b` are `null`, return `0`.