# MySQL Equivalent of NULLS LAST deployed through CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, null, sql-order-by

This is what I'm working with:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'order' => array('Job.deadline' => 'ASC'),
    'limit' => 500
);
```

Not all Jobs have a deadline, and at present, with this order, the NULLS appear above those with deadlines, so in effect I have this:

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
28/06/2012
29/06/2012
04/07/2012
```

I'm desperate to get this for clarity:

```
28/06/2012
29/06/2012
04/07/2012
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Is there a way I can achieve this through the paginate 'order' options in CakePHP.
Has anyone managed this at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should do:

```
'order' => array('ISNULL(Job.deadline)' => 'asc', 'Job.deadline' => 'asc')
```

Basically [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195311/476) in Cake syntax.

Comment: In fact, this is spot on! Cheers mate.