# How can I order by NULL in DQL?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm building an app using Symfony2 framework and using Doctrine ORM. I have a table with airlines for which some IATA codes are missing. I'm outputting a list, ordered by this IATA code, but I'm getting the undesirable result that the records with null IATA codes are sorted at the top.

In MySQL this is simple enough to do, with `ORDER BY ISNULL(code_iata), code_iata` but I'm clueless as to what the equivalent would be for DQL. I tried

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('airline')->orderBy('ISNULL(airline.codeIata), airline.codeIata', 'ASC')
```

but this gives me a syntax error.

The Doctrine docs give me no answer either. Is there a way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the following trick in DQL to order NULL values last

```
$em->createQuery("SELECT c, -c.weight AS HIDDEN inverseWeight FROM Entity\Car c ORDER BY inverseWeight DESC");
```

The `HIDDEN` keyword (available since Doctrine 2.2) will result in omitting the `inverseWeight` field from the result set and thus preventing undesirable [mixed results](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results).

(The sort fields value is inverted therefore the order has to be inverted too, that's why the query uses `DESC` order, not `ASC`.)

Credits belong to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last/8174026#8174026).

Comment: Does not works with other types, like Datetime data

Answer (score 16):

The most unobtrusive generic solution would be to use the `CASE` expression in combination with the `HIDDEN` keyword.

```sql
   SELECT e,
     CASE WHEN e.field IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HIDDEN _isFieldNull
     FROM FooBundle:Entity e
 ORDER BY _isFieldNull ASC
```

Works with both numeric as well as other field types and doesn't require extending Doctrine.

Comment: This works perfect!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do something similar to "NULLS LAST" in SQL (with PostgreSQL in my case):

```
ORDER BY freq DESC NULLS LAST
```

You can use the COALESCE function with the Doctrine Query Builder
(HIDDEN will hide the field "freq" on your query result set).

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
           ->addSelect('COALESCE(d.freq, 0) AS HIDDEN freq')
           ->orderBy('freq', 'DESC')
           ->setMaxResults(20);
```

Comment: thx Thomas, this saved my day. here how to sort with date: ->addSelect('COALESCE(news.date, \'0001-01-01\') AS HIDDEN date')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')

Answer (score 7):

Here it is an example for a custom walker to get exactly what you want. I have taken it from Doctrine in its github issues:

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/100

But the code as it is there didn't work for me in MySQL. I have modified it to work in MySQL, but I haven't test at all for other engines.

Put following walker class for example in `YourNS\Doctrine\Waler\` directory;

```
<?php

namespace YourNS\Doctrine\Walker;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class SortableNullsWalker extends SqlWalker
{
   const NULLS_FIRST = 'NULLS FIRST';
   const NULLS_LAST = 'NULLS LAST';

   public function walkOrderByClause($orderByClause)
   {
      $sql = parent::walkOrderByClause($orderByClause);

      if ($nullFields = $this->getQuery()->getHint('SortableNullsWalker.fields'))
      {
         if (is_array($nullFields))
         {
            $platform = $this->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->getName();
            switch ($platform)
            {
            case 'mysql':
               // for mysql the nulls last is represented with - before the field name
               foreach ($nullFields as $field => $sorting)
               {
                  /**
                   * NULLs are considered lower than any non-NULL value,
                   * except if a – (minus) character is added before
                   * the column name and ASC is changed to DESC, or DESC to ASC;
                   * this minus-before-column-name feature seems undocumented.
                   */
                  if ('NULLS LAST' === $sorting)
                  {
                     $sql = preg_replace_callback('/ORDER BY (.+)'.'('.$field.') (ASC|DESC)/i', function($matches) {
                        if ($matches[3] === 'ASC') {
                           $order = 'DESC';
                        } elseif ($matches[3] === 'DESC') {
                           $order = 'ASC';
                        }
                        return ('ORDER BY -'.$matches[1].$matches[2].' '.$order);
                     }, $sql);
                  }
               }
                  break;
            case 'oracle':
            case 'postgresql':
               foreach ($nullFields as $field => $sorting)
               {
                  $sql = preg_replace('/(\.' . $field . ') (ASC|DESC)?\s*/i', "$1 $2 " . $sorting, $sql);
               }
               break;
            default:
               // I don't know for other supported platforms.
               break;
               }
            }
         }

         return $sql;
   }
}
```

Then:

```
use YourNS\Doctrine\Walker\SortableNullsWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

[...]

$qb = $em->getRepository('YourNS:YourEntity')->createQueryBuilder('e');
$qb
   ->orderBy('e.orderField')
   ;

$entities = $qb->getQuery()
  ->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,  '\YourNS\Doctrine\Walker\SortableNullsWalker')
  ->setHint('SortableNullsWalker.fields', array(
     'sortOrder' => SortableNullsWalker::NULLS_LAST
  ))
  ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

DQL does not contain every function of plain SQL. Fortunately you can define your **custom DQL method** to accomplish this.

**Some resources:**

http://punkave.com/window/2012/07/24/for-the-php-crowd-adding-custom-functions-to-doctrine-2-dql

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the most sensible action to take, albeit quite convoluted. I see enough instructions on creating the custom function class, but how do I go about importing and implementing inside the QueryBuilder? I have added it to my global config.yml, I assume then I no longer need to import it inside every FormType class then. But how is it used inside the createQueryBuilder call?

Comment: I have the custom function defined as `isnull_string` inside my ORM config, and I implement it thusly: 
`$er->createQueryBuilder('airline')->orderBy('isnull_string(airline.codeIata), airline.codeIata', 'ASC');`

Which is still giving me a syntax error. Apparently CreateQueryBuilder doesn't support the full DQL syntax as CreateQuery does. Which is a shame since I don't think you can use createQuery inside the FormBuilderInterface (the option is explicitly called query_builder, after all).

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL will still sort a `NULL` value; it will just place it at the beginning of the result set if it was sorted `ASC`, and at the end if it was sorted `DESC`. Here, you're looking to sort `ASC`, but you want the `NULL` values to be at the bottom.

Unfortunately, as powerful as it is, Doctrine isn't going to offer much support here, since function support is limited, and most of it is limited to `SELECT`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` clauses. You actually wouldn't have a problem at all if any of the following were true about the QueryBuilder:

- `select()` accepted `ISNULL()`
- `orderBy()` or `addOrderBy()` supported `ISNULL()`
- the class supported the concept of `UNION`s (with this, you could run two queries: one where the `codeIata` was `NULL`, and one where it wasn't, and you could sort each independently)

So that said, you can go with the user-defined functions that ArtWorkAD mentioned already, or you could replicate that last point with two different Doctrine queries:

```
$airlinesWithCode = $er->createQueryBuilder("airline")
    ->where("airline.iataCode IS NULL")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
$airlinesWithoutCode = $er->createQueryBuilder("airline")
    ->where("airline.iataCode IS NOT NULL")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Then you can combine these into a single array, or treat them independently in your templates.

Another idea is to have DQL return everything in one data set, and let PHP do the heavy lifting. Something like:

```
$airlines = $er->findAll();
$sortedAirlines = array();
// Add non-NULL values to the end if the sorted array
foreach ($airlines as $airline)
    if ($airline->getCodeIata())
        $sortedAirlines[] = $airline;
// Add NULL values to the end of the sorted array
foreach ($airlines as $airline)
    if (!$airline->getCodeIata())
        $sortedAirlines[] = $airline;
```

The downside to both of these is that you won't be able to do `LIMIT`s in MySQL, so it might only work well for relatively small data sets.

Anyway, hope this gets you on your way!