# SQL order few records asc and the rest desc

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last)

I have a table with columns like this.

```
NULL
NULL
2012-10-12
NULL
2013-10-17
2012-10-17
```

I want to sort the date fields in asc and the NULL values to go to the last, to get something like this

```
2012-10-12
2012-10-17
2013-10-17
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

I did `select xyz from table order by xyz.abc asc;` which prints the reverse of this.

Also, played around the order_by with `case` and `IF` functions, but couldn't get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT `xyz` FROM `your_table`
ORDER BY (`abc` IS NULL),`abc`
```

Answer (score -1):

Try ::

```
    select xyz from table where abc is not null order by abc asc
    UNION 
    select xyz from table where abc is null
```

Comment: I tried this too, here it should be union all instead of union, moreover order by and union cannot be used in tandem