# Zend Framework order by ascending null values last

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I my order by clause I want to do something like

```
select MyDate
from MyTable
order by case when MyDate is null then 1 else 0 end, MyDate
```

how can I write

```
order by case when MyDate is null then 1 else 0 end, MyDate
```

in Zend
I already tried

```
->order('by case when MyDate is null then 1 else 0 end', 'MyDate')
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Following what I found on this article, [MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last), this maybe could work for you:

```
->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("-MyDate DESC"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice to provide us with error message or `echo $select` so we could see where problem is.

Try this:

```
->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('case when MyDate is null then 1 else 0 end, MyDate'));
```

Passing `Zend_Db_Expr` object always puts it in query 'as it is' with no modification.