# MySQL UNION SELECT statement order by two different columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column called "myorder". I want to only order the first 5 elements in ascending order by using the column "myorder" and then the rest of the elements ordererd by id in descending order. I've tried but I don't seem to get this 100%. I have created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f66fe8/8) with this simple example. Can anybody help me?

The order in the sqlfiddle should be: Blue, Brown, Yellow, Red, Green, Orange, Gray, Black, White.

Comment: [This](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/mysql/threads/312461/union-two-queries-and-preserve-sort) website suggests that an `order by` statement can only be used after the final `select` on a union. Is it possible to reverse the order of the `MYORDER` column where `1` and `5`, and `2` and `4` are swapped?

Comment: Can we have NULL value instead of zero when myorder is not specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try

`SELECT * from tbl ORDER BY IF(myorder=0, 2147483647, myorder) ASC, id DESC`

if by "first 5" you mean ones with nonzero `myorder`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What does that number in the middle do? A little explanation please. I'm the kind of person who wants to understand and not copy paste. Thank you!

Comment: In your order, you have it so that the nonzero `myorder` come first. This query accomplishes this by replacing zero values with a large number. How large? As large as an `int` can be in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

Append this to the end of your sql statement:

> ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3,4,5,1,2,9,8,7,6)

This will manually sort the results based on the id field in the specified order getting the colours in order.

Alternatively you could:

> ORDER BY FIELD(NAME, BLUE,BROWN,YELLOW......)

Answer (score 0):

Union does not preserves order, at least not in all databases. 
To get this done you need to select a fake column and use order on the results (total)

Here is a solution:

(

```
SELECT Id, myorder, myorder as fake, name from tbl WHERE myorder!=0) UNION 
(SELECT id, myorder, 2000 as fake,name  from tbl WHERE myorder=0) ORDER BY fake asc, id desc
```

This Will work in any case, as long as you keep the fake number high enough.

Answer (score 0):

Can we have NULL value instead of zero when myorder is not specified?

If so we can do this:

```
SELECT * from tbl ORDER BY -myorder DESC, id DESC
```

Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef9ee/4

Hint on forcing nulls to sort last: [MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement and the following trick (for example):

```
SELECT *, 
CASE myorder
    WHEN 0 THEN id
    ELSE 99999999 - myorder
END AS ord
FROM tbl
ORDER BY ord DESC
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f66fe8/76)