# ORDER BY field ASC with NULL items at end

Tags: mysql

I want to do an `ORDER BY` such that it would show the following:

```
- 1
- 3
- 5
- NULL
- NULL
```

If I do a `ORDER BY field ASC`, it would give me:

```
- NULL
- NULL
- 1
- 3
- 5
```

What would be the most straightforward way to do the first ordering?

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to do:

```
order by IFNULL(`field`, 18446744073709551615)
```

or select another max value for your type from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 2):

Order by 2 things. First by the condition if the values are null and then by the column values

```
ORDER BY field is not null,
         field ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, the cleanest way in to place a minus sign (-) before the column name in your ORDER BY and change the ASC to DESC.

So:
`ORDER BY column_name ASC`
Becomes:
`ORDER BY -column_name DESC`

I believe this is an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use the syntax: `select value from num order by isnull(value), value;`

To demonstrate:

```
create table nums (value int);
insert into nums values (1), (3), (5), (null), (null);
select value from nums order by isnull(value), value;

+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     3 |
|     5 |
|  NULL |
|  NULL |
+-------+
```