# Change how null value is sorted using orderBy()

Tags: sorting, laravel, sql-order-by, query-builder

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and have a query builder object. The column I am trying to order by is nullable. When the value is null it treats it as the lowest value. I need to make it treat null as the highest value.

```
public function sort($builder, $direction = 'asc')
{
    return $builder->orderBy('table.nullable_column', $direction);
}
```

Honestly I just need the null values to be last when sorting ascending and last when descending. Open to suggestions if Laravel doesn't have a way to handle this. Was unable to find anything else using google. Hopefully you guys can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple put a `-` sign before the column

```
public function sort($builder, $direction = 'asc')
{
    return $builder->orderBy('-table.nullable_column', $direction);
}
```

reference: [MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last)