# Order an array with null values last

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've added a `priority` value to sort a list of objects in ascending order. The value is optional on records, and in the production app there are a lot of records that exist where `priority` is null.

When I sort the list, it returns all the nulls first -- the expected behaviour should be to include the nulls last, sorted by created_at desc.

```
@company.spark_sessions.order('priority asc, created_at desc')
```

Is there a nice, standard Rails way to return null records at the *end* of the list?

The top comment on a thread from five years ago recommended adding arrays together to preserve order, which I'm not fond of.

Comment: You don't really need a Rails way, just a mysql way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last

Comment: Marking as a duplicate since there is no polyglot "rails way" to do this.