# Ordering asc then nulls in CakePHP pagination

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

I have this code in cakePHP

```
$this->paginate = [
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'Companies.name',
            'Grants.shortname',
            'amount',
            'contact',
            'LatestHistory.Histories__deadline',
            'Statuses.name'
        ],
        'order' => [
            'LatestHistory.Histories__deadline' => 'ASC',
            'Statuses.await' => 'DESC',
            'Statuses.name'
        ]
    ];
```

It orders by Histories deadline ASC, but the nulls come first, than the another records, where Histories deadline is not null. I would like, if the ASC list would be in the first place, than the nulls. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'Companies.name',
        'Grants.shortname',
        'amount',
        'contact',
        'LatestHistory.Histories__deadline',
        'Statuses.name'
    ],
    'order' => [
        '-LatestHistory.Histories__deadline' => 'DESC',
        'Statuses.await' => 'DESC',
        'Statuses.name'
    ]
];
```

Pay attention to the minus sign in front of `LatestHistory.Histories__deadline` and the `DESC` reversed order .

This technique is described in [MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last).

Comment: This is most likely to break when automatic identifier quoting is enabled, as the sign would be treated as being part of the identifier. Using a `CASE` expression is probably a better, more robust (and also cross DBMS compatible) solution.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I posted the quick solution, and was later going to expand my answer to add other options, but @drmonkeyninja beat me to it :) The above works for MySQL (specified by the OP), but will break with `'quoteIdentifiers' => true` (confirmed). So it will probably not work for CakePHP 2.x (haven't tested it though).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using two `order by` conditions in your query:-

```
ORDER BY LatestHistory.Histories__deadline is null, LatestHistory.Histories__deadline ASC
```

The first `order by` works by ordering the statement by whether it returns `true` or `false`.

So your Cake paginate query would look like:-

```
$this->paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'Companies.name',
        'Grants.shortname',
        'amount',
        'contact',
        'LatestHistory.Histories__deadline',
        'Statuses.name'
    ],
    'order' => [
        'LatestHistory.Histories__deadline is null',
        'LatestHistory.Histories__deadline' => 'ASC',
        'Statuses.await' => 'DESC',
        'Statuses.name'
    ]
];
```

Alternatively use `CASE WHEN`:-

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LatestHistory.Histories__deadline IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, LatestHistory.Histories__deadline ASC
```

Comment: This is probably a better answer. However, you may want to use `LatestHistory.Histories__deadline` => `ASC` instead. Also, change it to `LatestHistory.Histories__deadline ASC` on your second option.

Comment: Thanks @InigoFlores I missed that the OP wanted ascending order, I've updated accordingly.