# custom ORDER BY Clause - MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 columns to `ORDER BY` -- `date`, `day` ..

```
+------------------+---------------------+
| day_to_send      | date_to_send        |
+------------------+---------------------+
|     25           | 0000:00:00 00:00:00 |
|     18           | 0000:00:00 00:00:00 | 
|     11           | 0000:00:00 00:00:00 | 
|     NULL         | 2018-11-20 04:41:12 |
|     NULL         | 2019-04-11 10:50:12 |
|     NULL         | 2018-11-19 11:30:12 |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

Output should be

```
 1. 2018-11-19 11:30:12
 2. 2018-11-20 04:41:12
 3. 2019-04-11 10:50:12
 4. 11
 5. 18
 6. 25
```

I have tried so far, `date ASC/DESC`, and `day ASC/DESC` but i couldn't achieve this somehow.. any help would be highly appreciated.

```
->orderBy('date_to_send', 'ASC')
->orderBy('day_to_send', 'ASC')
```

I am using Laravel 4

**MY OUTPUT, What I am getting**

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype of your `date` column?

Comment: datetime @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: So you have 6 records you want sorted, 3 with no `day` column and 3 with no `date` column, right?

Comment: I really doubt that. MySQL datetime format values are in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, not the way you have described

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya He could just be writing the dates in that format for purpose of asking this question.

Comment: I have updated my question @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: @TimLewis, I want to sort the columns first `date` coloumns should be shown in `ASC` and then day should start in `ASC` too

Comment: i have 6 records ..

Comment: And 3 of them have `null` for `date`, while the other 3 have `null` for `day`?

Comment: yes correct.. for `date`, they will be null or 0000:00:00 00:00:00

Comment: Ok. One more thing, can you post the output you *are* getting? It might just be an issue where `null` is being sorted first and you are expecting it to be last, or vice-versa.

Comment: i have added a screenshot of my output in my question.. @TimLewis

Comment: Then yes, it looks like it's sorting correctly. If you have `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as your `null` dates, those are technically before `2018-11-19 16:41:00`. You'll likely have to add some conditional sorting. I'd suggest working this out in your MySQL client (MySQLWorkBench, etc.) and applying to Laravel after you've figured that out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last)

Comment: What MySQL version are you using by the way?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have found a solution to do this.. just pasting my answer if someone needed in future.. The sorting was not working properly due to `datatype` of my `day_to_send` column.

I have changed the `datatype` of this column from `varchar` to `int` and applied the below query and it worked..!

```
->orderBy('date_to_send', 'ASC')    
->orderBy('day_to_send', 'ASC')
```

Thanks to all those who contributed.. Cheers