# Trying to find a way to organize null values so they show last in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table with null values across the

```
row(counter, null 3456,10,null,45,null).
```

I am trying to make the data look like

```
(counter, 3456,10,45,null,null,null).
```

So far I have tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM alpha2
ORDER BY IS NULL( Value1, Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6);
```

- Value is the column name

I have also tried

```
SELECT * FROM alpha2 ORDER BY -rank DESC;


Counter Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6 <- columns
Count1  3456   10     45      null  null  null .   <-rows
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: `ORDER BY` doesn't order columns; it orders rows.  The columns are fixed in a query.  The fact that you want to do something like this suggests a flaw in your data model.

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench, would I need to order by the rows values then? Or different query altogether?

Answer (score 1):

On MS-SQL Server, the `ORDER BY ... ASC` clause will always place `NULL` values first.
On MS-SQL Server, the `ORDER BY ... DESC` clause will always place `NULL` values last.

On Oracle, the `ORDER BY ... ASC` clause will always place `NULL` values last.
On Oracle, the `ORDER BY ... DESC` clause will always place `NULL` values first.

The SQL standard does not explicitly define a default sort order for `Nulls`. Instead, on conforming systems, `Nulls` can be sorted before or after all data values by using the `NULLS FIRST` or `NULLS LAS`T clauses of the `ORDER BY` list, respectively. This is the case for Oracle RDBMS. 
MS-SQL Server does not implement this functionality.

Sample code for sorting nulls in MySQL:
Here, Data is assumed as Column and Table as Table:

```
    select Data
    from Table
    order by case when Data is null then 1 else 0 end, Data
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! The code works great but is there a way to sort the integers and nulls so that the row would have all the integers first and then the null last.

Comment: example = 1,2,3,null,null,null for each row?

Comment: Here is perfect answer for your question 
Hope this help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last

Comment: The question is about sorting columns not rows so I don't understand this answer and the linked answer is equally irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the link!