# SqlAlchemey nullslast order in relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm defining a relationship in my class and I need to apply a `nullslast` to the order_by.  How would I do this in the relationship or is there another way to go about it?

```
flags = relationship("Flag",
    backref=backref("box", lazy="select"),
    cascade="all,delete,delete-orphan", order_by="Flag._order",
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get what I wanted by following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last) and making the order_by negative with a desc.  Hope it works with more than mysql.

```
flags = relationship("Flag",
    backref=backref("box", lazy="select"),
    cascade="all,delete,delete-orphan", order_by="desc(-Flag._order)",
    )
```