# Complexe order query on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sorting

In my MySQL 5.5 database, I have a table of *commerces* which I need to sort first with the column **logo** (rows with logo entries **not null** first) and at the same time sort those rows alphabetically with the column **title**.

The result I need is this:

```
| Logo | Title  |
| ---  | ------ |
| img  | ATitle |
| img  | BTitle |
| img  | CTitle |
| ...  | ...    |
| NULL | ATitle |
| NULL | BTitle |
| ...  | ...    |
```

I tried this query already:

```
    SELECT * FROM commerces ORDER BY logo DESC, title ASC
```

But this query seems to sort the whole list without distinction to logo not null or null.

So my question is if there is a solution in an unique query to sort my rows as wanted?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This should work. Please provide a minimum reproducible example so one can have a look at it.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last

Comment: @Dashiloh Query works fine. What is the real issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write sql query using IS NULL in order by.

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY name IS NULL, name ASC
```

Please refer below link for more information.

https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-order-null-values-first-or-last-in-mysql