# Self-referential table ordering in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Given a table like this:

| taskId | nextTaskId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | NULL |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 8 | 4 |

I need the following order for output:

| taskId | nextTaskId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | NULL |

Is there any way to do this via MySQL query?

Comment: Not sure if you can do it in SQL. If you can, it will probably require a recursive CTE.

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last

Comment: I misread - yes, its more of hierarchical set.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursive CTE -

```
WITH RECURSIVE
self_ref_cte ( taskid, nexttaskid )
AS
( SELECT taskid, nexttaskid
          FROM self_ref WHERE taskid = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.taskid,  s.nexttaskid 
         FROM self_ref_cte c JOIN self_ref s
        ON s.taskid = c.nexttaskid 
)
SELECT * FROM self_ref_cte;
```

DB fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yVbrSwZoHY2Q3z56UTRAX/0).