# Cyclistic Bike Share SQL ORDER BY timestampdiff shows NULLS

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sql-order-by, dbeaver

I am attempting to complete the Google Data Analytics Certification Capstone Project regarding Cyclistic Bike Share data.  I downloaded the 2022 monthly data from here: https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html.

There are two datetime columns, started_at and ended_at, that contain the time a client rented and returned the bike.  Using these two columns and MySQL, I wanted to get the difference of those two to get a trip_length column.

Using DBeaver and Visual Studio Code, I am able to correctly display the data ordered by trip length in descending order:

```
SELECT 
    started_at,
    ended_at,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, started_at, ended_at) AS trip_length
FROM 
    bikes.processed
ORDER BY 
3 DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

However, every time I want to flip the order of the results (in ascending order), both DBeaver and Visual Studio Code show all data as NULLs.  I went over the data cleanup process and made sure to completely delete all tuples containing null variables.

I found a workaround, which is using the top answer here: [MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last#comment30590178_4195311)

```
SELECT 
    started_at,
    ended_at,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, started_at, ended_at) AS trip_length
FROM 
    bikes.processed
ORDER BY ISNULL(trip_length), trip_length ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

I am a bit uneasy about both systems showing nulls and me having to push the null results to the end.  Why did this happen?  Can I trust my analysis if some random nulls occurred?  Thank you so much!

The following answers showed all null answers:

```
SELECT 
    started_at,
    ended_at,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, started_at, ended_at) AS trip_length
FROM 
    bikes.processed
ORDER BY 3 ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

```
SELECT 
    started_at,
    ended_at,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, started_at, ended_at) AS trip_length
FROM 
    bikes.processed
ORDER BY ISNULL(trip_length), trip_length ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

I expected to find at least find the started_at and ended_at columns populated, but for some reason both systems only show columns with NULL inside them.

Comment: You should cater for nulls and invalid dates in your code since datediff will return null if either is true.

Comment: Hi P.  I thought I did a pretty good job of erasing nulls, so I don't know where they are coming from.  Does this happen in the real world?  I am doing a career switch, so I have anyone near me to bounce ideas with.

Is it okay to continue my analysis even though this issue with nulls occurred?  Is there a way to get rid of those shadow NULL values?