# Get most recent row for given ID

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

In the table below, how do I get just the **most recent row** with `id=1` based on the `signin` column, and not all 3 rows?

```
+----+---------------------+---------+
| id | signin              | signout |
+----+---------------------+---------+
|  1 | 2011-12-12 09:27:24 | NULL    |
|  1 | 2011-12-13 09:27:31 | NULL    |
|  1 | 2011-12-14 09:27:34 | NULL    |
|  2 | 2011-12-14 09:28:21 | NULL    |
+----+---------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Related: [Select row with most recent date per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038193/select-row-with-most-recent-date-per-user/17038667)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use the aggregate `MAX(signin)` grouped by id. This will list the most recent `signin` for each `id`.

```
SELECT 
 id, 
 MAX(signin) AS most_recent_signin
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
```

To get the whole single record, perform an `INNER JOIN` against a subquery which returns only the `MAX(signin)` per id.

```
SELECT 
  tbl.id,
  signin,
  signout
FROM tbl
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(signin) AS maxsign FROM tbl GROUP BY id
  ) ms ON tbl.id = ms.id AND signin = maxsign
WHERE tbl.id=1
```

Comment: Here's what worked based on your **first** answer: `SELECT id, MAX(signin) FROM tbl GROUP BY id WHERE id=1;`

Comment: I tried to implement the 2nd solution (to get the whole row) on my own situation, but I always get an empty result set

Comment: @rantsh xQbert's answer had the correct version of what I originally had above, but I prefer the solution I just changed it ot.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you meant you prefer my solution? I wouldn't mind getting an upvote on my answer if that's the case

Comment: @rantsh Ah, I hadn't noticed you had added a similar thing to what I just modified, except via `USING` instead of an explicit `ON`. You got a +1 :)

Comment: the best way to find MAX value

Comment: I notice the output would be difference if I use LEFT JOIN. What might be the reason?

Comment: @OliverBird If you get different results from a left join I couldn't say without seeing the table data.

Comment: it's hard for me to post it, at least I noticed it and would be mindful each time as I applied this. TY!

Answer (score 100):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  id = 1
ORDER  BY signin DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

The obvious index would be on `(id)`, or a [multicolumn index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on `(id, signin DESC)`.

Conveniently for the case, MySQL sorts `NULL` values *last* in descending order. That's what you typically want if there can be `NULL` values: the row with the latest not-null `signin`.

To get `NULL` values  first:

```
ORDER BY signin IS NOT NULL, signin DESC
```

You may want to append more expressions to `ORDER BY` to get a deterministic pick from (potentially) multiple rows with `NULL`.
The same applies without `NULL` if `signin` is not defined `UNIQUE`.

Related:

- [mysql order by, null first, and DESC after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307613/mysql-order-by-null-first-and-desc-after)

The SQL standard does not explicitly define a default sort order for `NULL` values. The behavior varies quite a bit across different RDBMS. See:

- https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/ordering-behavior/#null-ordering-behavior

But there *are* the `NULLS FIRST` / `NULLS LAST` clauses defined in the SQL standard and supported by most major RDBMS, but not by MySQL. See:

- [SQL how to make null values come last when sorting ascending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498648/sql-how-to-make-null-values-come-last-when-sorting-ascending/12767777#12767777)
- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Comment: This feels like the cleanest way of doing it !

Comment: Consider creating index for signin column, it will speed up the process significantly

Comment: Use `SELECT TOP 1 *` and remove the `LIMIT 1` last line. if using SQL Server.  Use the above if MySQL or Postgres.

Comment: Cleanest . . . . . . . .

Comment: Simple and clean!

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: How do you get the results for each id? Can group by be used in this?

Comment: @Edward: There are various ways, depending on exact requirements. This works on MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800572/939860 `DISTINCT ON` is one way in Postgres. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860 And here's how to translate that to MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17673457/939860

Answer (score 10):

Building on @xQbert's answer's, you can avoid the subquery AND make it generic enough to filter by any ID

```
SELECT id, signin, signout
FROM dTable
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT id, MAX(signin) AS signin
  FROM dTable
  GROUP BY id
) AS t1 USING(id, signin)
```

Comment: Hi how does this query work and is it more efficient than xQbert's answer?  Both queries run at about the same time for me and I don't understand the using part of the query replacing what is usually and on.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select [insert your fields here]
from tablename 
where signin = (select max(signin) from tablename where ID = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tb1 ORDER BY signin DESC) GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I needed to get the last version of page content translation, in other words - to get that specific record which has highest number in version column. So I select all records ordered by version and then take the first row from result (by using LIMIT clause).

```
SELECT *
FROM `page_contents_translations`
ORDER BY version DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Way To Achieve**

I know it's an old question 
You can also do something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id=1 ORDER BY signin DESC
```

In above, query the first record will be the most recent record.

For only one record you can use something like

```
SELECT top(1) * FROM Table WHERE id=1 ORDER BY signin DESC
```

Above query will only return one latest record.

Cheers!