# mysql order by, null first, and DESC after

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How can I order DESC by a field, but list the NULL values first?

So I'm having a table:

```
reuestId | offerId | offerTitle
1        | 1       | Alfa
NULL     | 2       | Beta
2        | 3       | Gamma
```

I want to select them so that the results would be:

```
NULL | 2 | Beta
2    | 3 | Gamma
1    | 1 | Alfa
```

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY [reuestId] IS NULL DESC, [reuestId] DESC
```

should work (for mySql)

Comment: Or subquery to category

Answer (score 33):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableX
ORDER BY (requestId IS NOT NULL)
       , requestId DESC
```

Comment: I think this answer is opposite of the first one?

Comment: @xi.lin: No, the first one puts `IS NULL` *(which is essentially a function which returns a 1 or a 0)* in DESC order, this one puts `IS NOT NULL` in ascending order.  They're equivalent.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Thanks for the explain! I just wrongly thought IS NULL is a filter instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY -column`

This will sort rows ascending order but the values negated, where top rows are rows with null value.

Answer (score 0):

I know the op is tagged with mysql, but if anyone got here looking for a solution for SQLServer, where is seems `is null` is not supported in the `order by` clause, use the following:

```
ORDER BY iif(requestId IS NULL,1,0)
       , requestId DESC
```