# Order by NULL in Propel 1

Tags: php, mysql, propel

How is it possible to add an `ORDER BY columnName IS NULL DESC, columnName DESC` to a Propel query. I have the same problem [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307613/mysql-order-by-null-first-and-desc-after) but I can't seem to find a proper solution using Propel methods. Since this clause will be embedded in a rather complex query building process, I do not want to just move to plain SQL.

Comment: Whats does `columnName` contain?

Comment: `columnName` contains a column name or a (quoted) qualified column name, e.g. `\`tbl\`.\`col\``. In my case the column is of type `DATETIME`. It is of the same value in the first and the second occurrence.

Comment: So you want to sort results by latest `DATETIME` first in which `NULL` values should be on top. Right?

Comment: @Samir Correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use ModelCriteria you could try:

```
$query = YourEntityQuery::create('e')
    ->withColumn('e.sortColumn IS NULL', 'isSortColumnNull')
    ->orderBy('isSortColumnNull', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('e.sortColumn', 'desc');
```