# How to get NULL at the top of the sort?

Tags: mysql, sql

Two tables are defined:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `score` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `online` (
  `user_id` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);
```

How to combine the tables so that the result would be sorted by the score field from the largest to the smallest but at the top there were records with the value NULL?
This query does not sort the second sample:

```
(SELECT * FROM `online` JOIN `users` USING(`user_id`) WHERE `score` IS NULL)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `online` JOIN `users` USING(`user_id`) WHERE `score` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `score` DESC)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql order by, null first, and DESC after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307613/mysql-order-by-null-first-and-desc-after)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two keys in the sort:

```
SELECT *
FROM `online` o JOIN
     `users`
     USING (user_id)
ORDER BY (`score` IS NULL) DESC, Score DESC;
```

MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So, `DESC` puts the true values first.

Incidentally, your version would look like it works if you used `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`.  However, it is not guaranteed that the results are in any particular order **unless you explicitly have an `ORDER BY`**.

The `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates and in doing so rearranges the data.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Seems for USING need brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select * from online join users using (user_id) order by ifnull(score, 10) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select * from
(
SELECT *,1 as ord FROM `online` JOIN `users` USING(`user_id`) WHERE `score` IS NULL
UNION
SELECT *,2  FROM `online` JOIN `users` USING(`user_id`) WHERE `score` IS NOT NULL
)A ORDER BY ord asc,`score` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by Nulls Last` in the end of your sql to show nulls on the first.