# Laravel Eloquent OrderBy show empty/null column value first

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Currently I can get all the records with simple `orderBy` only

But what I'm trying to do is to show all records

if `date` column either empty or null it should be shown as first and all the following data that doesn't empty/null will follows.

```
$data = \App\Models\Event::where('deleted_at',NULL)
->orderBy('date','DESC')
->paginate(6);
return $data;
```

**Current Output**

`id | name  |  date`

`3 | text3 | 2020-08-03`

`2 | text4 | 2020-08-02`

`4 | text5 | 2020-08-01`

`1 | text1 |`

**Example of output trying to achieve**

`id | name  |  date`

`1 | text1 |`

`2 | text2 | 2020-08-03`

`3 | text3 | 2020-08-02`

`4 | text4 | 2020-08-01`

As you can see, the `date` values who blanks are shown first and all the data follows with `orderBy` `date` as `DESC`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644072/how-to-sort-null-values-last-using-eloquent-in-laravel see this link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql order by, null first, and DESC after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307613/mysql-order-by-null-first-and-desc-after)

Comment: can we do this in eloquent way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the minus sign with a raw order query:

```php
$data = \App\Models\Event::where('deleted_at',NULL)
  ->orderByRaw('-date','DESC')
  ->paginate(6);
return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` for your ordering criteria like

```
$data = \App\Models\Event::where('deleted_at',NULL)
    ->orderByRaw("case when date is null or date = '' then 1 else 0 end",'DESC')
    ->paginate(6);
```