# mysql query for most recent and unique ids

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a mysql query. I have a table with columns entryID, nodeID, latitude, longitude, and timestamp. I want to retrieve the most recent lat/lon entry for each nodeID, i.e. I want to retrieve exactly one entry (the most recent) per unique nodeID.

Comment: If you down vote, say why. It would be great for everyone to know.

Comment: possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523374/mysql-get-most-recent-record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT nodeID, MAX(timestamp) AS Latesttimestamp
   FROM tablename
   GROUP BY nodeID
) AS t2 ON t1.timestamp = t2.Latesttimestamp AND t1.nodeID = t2.nodeID
```

Comment: @Gavman - You're welcome any time :)