# Select rows from Database Table based on date and Distinct field

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to select multiple rows from a database based on the date (descending), and making sure that I do not get any rows that have the same part number. So basically I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT `part_number`, `second_field`, `third_field`, `date`
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY DISTINCT('part_number'), order_date DESC
```

I know the syntax for this query is not correct, I am just not sure how to do it. I think there is a possibility I might need to use ORDER BY too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `,` and change the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT `part_number`, `second_field`, `third_field`, `date`
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY part_number
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately your query does not get the parts with the most recent date - which is what I was looking for. I am not sure why. The above answer I made shows a query I found which does work.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research on how to write a query according to my needs. I've found the best way is using the following query:

```
SELECT `part_number`, `second_field`, `third_field`, MAX(`date`) AS most_recent_date
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY `part_number`
```

I found the information I needed in the best answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523374/mysql-get-most-recent-record).