# MySQL SUM with CASE choose latest record by date

Tags: mysql

I've got the SUM CASE statements working properly. The issue is that I have multiple records with similar criteria, so I'd like to select the latest record by date.

```
 SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN planning like 'Rotation%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN assessmentanddata like 'Collects%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN path like 'Same%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN place like 'Move%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN pace like 'Timer%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN classroommanagement like 'Restating%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN teacherrole like 'Mini%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN studentengagement like 'Follow%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN studentcollaboration like 'Collects%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN technology like 'Technology%' THEN 1 else 0 END)  AS p1
    from ruberic where schoolId = 1
```

A sample from the table will be these 3 columns of DATE, SCHOOLID, and TEACHERID:

> 2016-12-05    1   1 -> This record will be fine
>
> 2016-12-05    1   4 -> Select only this when compared with the record below
>
> 2016-12-05    1   4

Comment: Perhaps the down votes are due to an unfinished question. There is no `FROM` or `WHERE` clause. Based on my understanding of the preface, the `CASE` is mostly a distraction. See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523374/mysql-get-most-recent-record

Comment: First post, worried about the editing, missed the 'from'/'where'.

Comment: Work on it piece by piece. If your starting query works, then go on to add "when schoolId and teacherId are the same" to your `WHERE` clause. Once you have that done, check the (many) other questions on SO about grabbing the most recent record.

Comment: If you wish to clarify, please edit the question. That's a mess in the comments.

Comment: thanks for bearing with me alttag....

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on what I see (I don't see the field name for date so assumed date)

This uses a correlates subquery and an exists statement to identify the max(date) for each teacherID and school and then limits the main dataset by this subset through the coloration.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN planning like 'Rotation%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN assessmentanddata like 'Collects%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN path like 'Same%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN place like 'Move%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN pace like 'Timer%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN classroommanagement like 'Restating%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN teacherrole like 'Mini%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN studentengagement like 'Follow%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN studentcollaboration like 'Collects%' THEN 1 else 0 END +
        CASE WHEN technology like 'Technology%' THEN 1 else 0 END)  AS p1
FROM
    ruberic R1
WHERE
    schoolId = 1 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT Null 
                FROM ruberic r2
                WHERE R2.SchoolID = R1.SchoolID
                  AND R2.TeacherID = R1.TeacherID
                GROUP BY SchoolID, TeacherID
                HAVING R1.Date = MAX(R2.Date) )
```