# HOW CAN I SELECT ORDERS TABLE?

Tags: sql

My table is:

```
ORDER ID     LINENUMBER      PRODUCT 
----------------------------------------
    XYZ           0          PHONE
    XYZ           1          COMPUTER
    XXX           0          MOUSE
    XXX           1          TV
    XXX           2          COMPUTER
    ZYY           0          TV
    XKX           0          PHONE
    XKX           1          HEADPHONE
```

I want products in last 3 orders

```
ORDER ID    LINENUMBER       PRODUCT
-------------------------------------------
   XKX           1           HEADPHONE 
   XKX           0           PHONE
   ZYY           0           TV 
   XXX           2           COMPUTER  
   XXX           1           TV 
   XXX           0           MOUSE
```

Comment: How do you define "last three orders"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "last three", unless a column specifies the ordering.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: 'select top 3 * from orders 
order by desc orderid ' 
does this do your work?

Comment: I think you want to try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523374/mysql-get-most-recent-record

Answer (score 1):

Add created_at column to the table with type timestamp with timezone.

Define its value to be by default `now()`.
Now you can pick the last three orders by the latest dates on the table.

On your select query add ORDER BY clause:

```
...
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 3;
```