# Order by time ASC and skip null value

Tags: sqlite

I have db which has time column and this column contains numbers as strings and if there's no time the field contains null value .
I order the select statement by time column but the rows have null value appears first and I want them to be at the end of the list 
thnx

Comment: You can try [SQL how to make null values come last when sorting ascending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498648/sql-how-to-make-null-values-come-last-when-sorting-ascending/1498667#1498667)

Comment: Thnx man 
That's did the trick :)