# Cakephp pagination with more than one order condition

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination

Currently I have a table called as 'Users'. With columns like

```
Id, name, image, is_active, etc, etc, created, modified
```

I am setting up a pagination, where it will display all Users one by one, on click of next button(in the view)

here not all Users will have images. So my pagination order will be: to show users who have images first. Followed by  Users who don't have images.

So far I have this

```
    $this->paginate = array(
      'limit' => 1,
      'conditions' => array(
        'User.is_active' => 0
        ),
      'order' => array(
        'User.image' => 'DESC'
        ),
      'group' => array(
        'User.id'
        )    
      );
```

What I want is now, the view to **FIRST display a *random* User, who has image, every time the page refreshes OR on the first load of the page.** Followed by other Users who have images ,and then followed by Users who don't have images.

this query works fine in phpmyadmin sql panel. But I am not sure how do I write a cakephp paginate query for it

```
select * User order by image<>' ' desc,rand()
```

If you think I am missing any more data, please ask. I'll write it in comments

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this answer [SQL how to make null values come last when sorting ascending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498648/sql-how-to-make-null-values-come-last-when-sorting-ascending) and try to change it with CakePHP conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can set. I believe this works for the pagination order as well.

```
    public $order = array(
        'ISNULL(Users.image) ASC',
        'RAND() * User.id'
    );
```

But this makes all the users randomized. I don't know how you may do it to show only in the first record a random user with the order field. I would suggest using a custom function in which you may choose a random row and put it in the top of the array.