# Advanced ordering of an attribute in an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a set of users. They have many requests.

```
# user.rb
has_many :requests
```

now I'd like to sort them by the **last** request `created_at` timestamp.

So if that a user has the most recent request (the one where `created_at` is closest to the current time) they're #1 etc.

Any ideas?

I've tried

```
User.includes(:requests).order('requests.created_at')
```

however that sorts them by the first request created_at timestamp which is obviously not what I want. I wish to only retrieve their last request. Then sort the users last requests by their created at date and order the users by that.

**Update:**
Also if the user doesn't have any requests, they should be at the bottom. Now they get placed on top if they don't have any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.joins(:requests).includes(:requests).order('requests.created_at desc')
```

You need to `joins` it so it will sort on the join table.

`includes` will just preload your `requests` for you, it won't help you to sort the `requests`.

> **UPDATE**

Borrowing from [SQL how to make null values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1498667/1301840)

To incorporate into this case, it probably looks something like this

```
User.joins(:requests).includes(:requests).order('CASE WHEN requests.created_at IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END asc, requests.created_at desc')
```

> First order would put the null ones at the bottom, then order by date desc

Comment: Any idea on how I can sort it so that also user whom don't have any requests come last? Currently they're first.

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort in descending order. Try

```
User.includes(:requests).order('requests.created_at desc').first()
```