# SQL Order By on multiple columns containing Nulls

Tags: sql, null, sql-order-by, case

I have a table containing multiple columns, and I want to order by three of the columns within the table. I want to order by lot, then unit, and lastly number. Lot and Unit can contain nulls (need them listed at the bottom) whereas Number column does not contain Null. I've tried a bunch of case statements but its not giving the desired result. - Order by ... Nulls last is not an option.

| Lot | Unit | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | 500 |
| Null | Null | 425 |
| Null | Null | 424 |
| Null | 7 | 419 |
| Null | 9 | 450 |
| 25 | Null | 475 |
| 22 | Null | 486 |
| 22 | Null | 485 |
| 19 | 7 | 465 |
| 19 | 9 | 432 |

Desired result:

| Lot | Unit | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 7 | 465 |
| 19 | 9 | 432 |
| 22 | Null | 485 |
| 22 | Null | 486 |
| 25 | Null | 475 |
| Null | 7 | 419 |
| Null | 9 | 450 |
| Null | Null | 424 |
| Null | Null | 425 |
| Null | Null | 500 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: this was addressed here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498648/sql-how-to-make-null-values-come-last-when-sorting-ascending check it you find multiple answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do order by checking the nulls:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN lot IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
         , lot 
         , CASE WHEN unit IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
         , unit 
         , number
```

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged your question SQL, but not mentioned the database.  Standard SQL has a very convenient way to do what you want:

```
order by Lot nulls last, Unit nulls last, Number
```

Not all databases support `nulls last` and `nulls first`, but this is the standard SQL solution.