# Is there a way to treat null as the maximum value in MySQL without modifying the existing query?

Tags: mysql

We are migrating our back-end database from Oracle to MySQL. The front-end application is built on Access. The problem is that Oracle and MySQL handle nulls differently, which changes the order in which they are displayed in the front-end application: in Oracle, nulls are considered maximum values, but in MySQL, nulls are considered minimum values. I can change the order in which nulls are displayed by changing the query in the front-end application, but I would like to reduce the amount of change if possible, so I would like to be able to configure MySQL on the back-end to consider nulls as maximum values. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL how to make null values come last when sorting ascending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498648/sql-how-to-make-null-values-come-last-when-sorting-ascending)

Comment: MySQL have no NULLS FIRST/LAST sorting option or system option. You'd use `ORDER BY column IS [NOT] NULL, {other sorting expressions}`.

Comment: @KenY-N Thank you for your suggestion, but it seems that we need to change the query used in Access. I would like to avoid it.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your advice. Although I have read some references and there seems to be no option, someone may know the option, so I posted this question. Anyway it is glad to know there's completely no option to change null treatment.