# Why does this SQL order null values last?

Tags: sql

This will apparently put null values for myDate at the bottom of the result set. What's the logic behind how this is being executed?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE ...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN myDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, myDate;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN myDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
          myDate
```

The first expression for the order by says "Give the `NULL` values a value of 1 (for the sort) and non-`NULL` values a value of 0".  Well, you are sorting in ascending order, so the `NULL` values go last.

If you want them first, use `desc`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN myDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
          myDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN myDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, myDate;
```

When `myDate` is null the expression will return 1.  Otherwise it will return 0.  1 is greater than 0, so when ordering by the result of that expression in ascending order (the default), `null` values are moved to the end.